# Преобразовать список с вложенными словарями в JSON

Tags: python, json, list, словари, dict

Имеется следующая запись:

```
r = [{'aa': '"yes": 51', 'ab': '"no": 22',
      'bb': '"yes": 56', 'ba': '"no": 60'},
     {'aa': '"yes": 39', 'ab': '"no": 10',
      'bb': '"yes": 59', 'ba': '"no": 30'},
     {'aa': '"yes": 30', 'ab': '"no": 31',
      'bb': '"yes": 54', 'ba': '"no": 73'}]
```

необходимо преобразовать в JSON типа:

```
[
    [
        {
            "yes": 51,
            "no": 22
        },
        {
            "yes": 22,
            "no": 60
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "yes": 39,
            "no": 10
        },
        {
            "yes": 59,
            "no": 30
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "yes": 30,
            "no": 31
        },
        {
            "yes": 54,
            "no": 73
        }
    ]
]
```

К сожалению сам одолеть не смог =(

Comment: а по какому принципу получается такой json?

Comment: вот и мне хотелось бы знать...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот вам заготовка для разбора.

```
from ast import literal_eval

ll = []
for d in r:
    for v in d.values():
        x,y = v.split(':')
        ll.append({literal_eval(x): int(y)})
```

В результате получается такой список:

```
[{'yes': 51},
 {'no': 22},
 {'yes': 56},
 {'no': 60},
 {'yes': 39},
 {'no': 10},
 {'yes': 59},
 {'no': 30},
 {'yes': 30},
 {'no': 31},
 {'yes': 54},
 {'no': 73}]
```

Осталось только в JSON это собственно разместить попарно, пока мне лень дальше разбираться.